# How to get a Twilio worker statistics based on the minutes in nodejs

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

As mentioned in the Twilio document (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/worker-statistics) that specify the parameters Minutes, StartDate, EndDate to retrieve the worker statistics but i tried in many ways to fetch based on 240 minutes (4 hours),its giving default 15 minutes worker statistics every time on request and there is no proper document on nodeJS.

please find the code for nodeJs below

```
client.workspace.workers(workerSid).statistics.get({}, function(err, responseData) {
    if(!err) {
        console.log(responseData.cumulative.reservations_accepted);
    }
});
```

Someone help to resolve this issue, Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code looks like it uses v2 of the library, which is no longer supported, so I'd recommend upgrading to v3.

Comment: You said you've tried "many ways." What exactly have you tried? (My first guess would be `.get({ Minutes: 240 }, ...`, but I don't know if you've already tried that.)

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As smarx has said, it does look like you're using the version 2 syntax for this. I recommend that you use the version 3 [Twilio module for Node](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node).

When you are using that version, then you can get the [statistics for a worker](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/worker-statistics) over the last 4 hours with the following code:

```
const accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const authToken  = 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY';
const workspaceSid = 'WSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const workerSid = 'WKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.taskrouter.v1
  .workspaces(workspaceSid)
  .workers(workerSid)
  .statistics()
  .fetch({ minutes: 240 })
  .then((responseData) => {
     console.log(responseData);
   });
```

Note, you pass the `minutes` parameter to `fetch`.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Actually i am using the version 3 Twilio code. I tried in your way before its not working. getting a default result 15 minutes.

Comment: I just ran this code and the `start_time` and `end_time` in the response was for 4 hours. 
     
     `{ start_time: '2017-09-28T09:04:19Z',
     end_time: '2017-09-28T13:04:19Z'`

Comment: If you are having trouble still, can you post the current code that you are using and an example of the results (blocking out sensitive details).